# Is it correct to say "one year up in India"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that I have just completed one year in India.
Is the following sentence correct?

> One year up in India...

Comment: I don't know about Indian English (which has quite a few idioms of its own), but this wouldn't be used in British or American English.

Comment: actually i am not interested in indian english version

Answer (score 3):

*Up* can be used to mean *over* or *done* in some cases (think *time's up* or *the game is up*). That may be OP's intent.

In that case, *My first year in India is up* would make sense and, as an even less formal version, *one year up in India* is quite comprehensible, though it would be improved by sticking a verb in there.

> *One year['s] up in India, and I still don't know the difference between kulcha and roti.*

That said, I might call this structure atypical, and if OP is in search of a more standard way to express the same idea, phrases such as *after one year in India* or *having spent a year in India* would do.

Comment: it's a facebook status :P

Answer (score 2):

Well it's a sentence fragment, so per se it can't really be "correct". Still, the use of "up" here doesn't really make sense, unless you're referring loosely to the direction of India from your previous/current location (e.g. on a map). I'd have thought it'd be sufficient just to say

> One year in India...

That said, it is at least grammatically correct, insofar as it may be used as *part* of a sentence. However, to give any meaningful advice on wording, more context is needed.

Comment: it's a facebook status :P

Answer (score 0):

That only makes sense if you are currently “below” the place you are referencing. Below could mean by altitude or by latitude. For example, “up in the highlands of Tibet” (up by altitude), or “up in northern Alberta” (up by latitude).

I have a feeling that “up in Antarctica” wouldn’t work because people use up–down for the north–south axis only, not for a high latitude in the southern hemisphere. But “up on the Antarctic plateau” just possibly might be ok, because there’s two miles of ice beneath you.

Even though this question topic is [prepositions](/questions/tagged/prepositions), that’s not what we’re dealing with here.  In this context, *up* is an adverb, not a preposition.

Answer (score 0):

Using "one year up in India..." probably is not incorrect, and some people will understand it as a reference to time completed, but many won't.  More idiomatic is "one year *along* in India...".  Either way, one faces the risk of a dangling participle when starting a sentence with such a phrase.